# Variable Referenced before Assignment Error - How to use variables across multiple functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

I am trying to recreate a human population simulator. It's quite basic and is currently only using 3 variables. Here is my code:

```py
pop = 7000000000
int = 5

#Clear
def cls():
    print "\n" * 80

#Main script
def MS():
    cls()
    print "Population =", pop, "Intelligence =", int
    print ""
    print "Do You:"
    print "A) Increase Population"
    print "B) Increase Intelligence"
    choice = raw_input("Option:")
    if choice == "a" :
        print "option a"
    elif choice == "A" :
        print "option A"
    elif choice == "b" :
        intel()
    elif choice == "B" :
        intel()

#Increase Intelligence
def intel():
    int = int + 3

MS()
```

`Int` is my intelligence variable and `intel` my intelligence increase function name.

I want to know why I am getting the :

> "local variable 'int' referenced before assignment" Error

when I call the int() function. How do I fix it so I'm able to use my variables in multiple functions?

Comment: Please don't shadow the name `int`.  Use a different name for that variable.  It'll make things safer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pop` and `int` are assigned outside any function and are called *global variables*.  Variables assigned inside functions are called *local variables*.  To assign to a global variable inside a function, it must be declared global first:

```
def intel():
    global int
    int = int + 3
```

Note that `int` is the name of a type in Python, and shouldn't be used as a variable name:  This will cause problems later:

```
>>> int
<type 'int'>
>>> int(5.1)      # this works
5
>>> int=1
>>> int(5.1)      # now it is broken
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

This is called *shadowing builtins* and should be avoided.  Use a different variable name.

Answer (score 2):

In [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) , variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a new value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local. If a variable is ever assigned a new value inside the function, the variable is implicitly local, and you need to explicitly declare it as ‘global’.

Modify your intel() as shown below

```
def intel():
    global int
    int = int + 3
```